# How to modify ethernet adapter advanced properties without PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I need to change ethernet adapter advanced properties (EEE, Interrupt Moderation, Flow Control, Wake on Magic Packet etc) on multiple computers running on Windows 7.

[image]

Doing it manually is tedious and prone to mistakes. Sadly, PowerShell 2.0 doesn't support NetAdapterAdvancedProperty commands.

Would it be possible to modify the adapter drivers and set up custom defaults, so the system would load correct settings during driver installation?

Or is there any third party utility that could modify the settings, preferably from the command line?

Anything that would make the proccess easier would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can’t you just install the current version of PowerShell 4 on Windows 7?

Comment: It seems that it can only achieved by command or manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information can be found in the registry under this key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

You still need to determine the correct adapter among the adapters found
as sub-keys under the above key.

Here are the properties I found in the registry for my adapter (in Windows 10):

[image]

An example PowerShell 2.0 script for manipulating similar values can be found
in the article
[Configure iSCSI Network Cards as per Microsoft Best Practices PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Configure-iSCSI-Network-81232a5e/view/Reviews).

Comment: This part of the registry cannot be accessed in Windows 7 for some reason. Have tried on multiple machines with multiple versions of W7, from administrator's account, the result is always the same
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHTO7.png

Comment: Did you try with Run as Administrator?

Comment: You are right, I needed to run regedit with Run as Administrator. It works, thank you very much!